# Executing Async tasks in fragments

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am attempting to execute an async task in a fragment after converting my activities into fragments. When I call my async task from the activity I have to pass 'this' with it in order to allow the async task to change text and things after it receives the information. I am a bit confused on how to do this all with fragments. Here is what I got so far:

I execute the asynck task with:

```
new GetYourTopTasteBeers(this).execute(url);
```

the code for the async task is:

```
public class GetYourTopTasteBeers extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public GetYourTopTasteBeers (Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting beers");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);


            //acces listview
            ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.topTasteBeers);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<ShortBeerInfo> tasteList = new ArrayList<ShortBeerInfo>();



            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                String beer = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("beer");
                String rate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rate");
                String beerID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                String breweryID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("breweryID");


                int count = i + 1;

                beer = count + ". " + beer;


                //create object
                ShortBeerInfo tempTaste = new ShortBeerInfo(beer, rate, beerID , breweryID);

                //add to arraylist
                tasteList.add(tempTaste);


                //add items to listview
                ShortBeerInfoAdapter adapter1 = new ShortBeerInfoAdapter(c ,R.layout.brewer_stats_listview, tasteList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

                //set up clicks
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        ShortBeerInfo o=(ShortBeerInfo)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                        String tempID = o.id;
                        String tempBrewID = o.brewery;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c, tempID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();

                        //todo: change fragment to beer page

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(c, BeerPage2.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("id", tempID);
                        myIntent.putExtra("breweryID", tempBrewID);
                        c.startActivity(myIntent);


                    }
                });




            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

My problem is that I can not pass 'this' from a fragment...

Bonus Question:

Also as you can see I am not done converting my code for the fragments. I need to change this to load a fragment instead of change activity:

```
//todo: change fragment to beer page
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(c, BeerPage2.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("id", tempID);
                        myIntent.putExtra("breweryID", tempBrewID);
                        c.startActivity(myIntent);
```

HOw can I pass values between fragments like I am doing between activities in that above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass `this` because in this situation `this` referrers to your fragment, which doesn't extend `Context`. But you need `Context` (your `GetYourTopTasteBeers` takes `Context` as a parameter):

```
public GetYourTopTasteBeers (Context context)
```

Instead, pass your `Activity` like so:

```
new GetYourTopTasteBeers(getActivity()).execute(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `Fragment`s don't admit `this`, you may call `getActivity()` instead which will provide the context you need to execute the `AsyncTask`.

Be careful, though, as running an `AsyncTask` within a `Fragment` may lead to return a result to the caller `Activity` that has already been destroyed at the time your `AsyncTask` concluded its process. It's necessary to take additional precautions, and always check whether the `Fragment` hasn't already been destroyed. This can be done using `this.isAdded()` in your `Fragment`.

A good practice is to cancel your `AsyncTask` in the `onStop()` and `onPause()` methods. That will make the `onPostExecute()` not execute code if the `Fragment` is not active anymore (getActivity() would return null).

Comment: Cancelling your `AsyncTask` in `onStop()` is a good practice indeed. But don't do it in `onPause()`. Activity is still present after `onPause()` is executed, so there's no need in cancelling.

Comment: It should be stopped if there's any risk something will be updated within that pause. However it might happen that you need it running even if it's paused (for instance, a TCP socket)